# How can i change interval carousel bootstrap in wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Im wp newbie , i have installed pixel-linear theme and want to change time interval carousel(slider) in this theme, please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this below code.

add javascript in header/footer.php file

```
// interval is in milliseconds. 1000 = 1 second - so 1000 * 10 = 10 seconds

$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 1000 * 10
});
```

Comment: Happy to Help  :)